# dont show image with data url in jsp page

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am java begginer developer and i have a problem in display image in jsp page .I using java spring mvc and get the image from aws bucket this is my code in jsp page :

```
<img   alt="fgfg"   src="${Url}"  width="200" height="200"/>
```

this is my code in controler :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editContact(HttpServletRequest request,ModelMap map) {

int contactId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("contacting_id"));
Contacting Contacting = contactDAO.get(contactId);
User User=contactDAO.getUserByUserID(Integer.parseInt(Contacting.getUser_id()));
User.setFull_name(User.getFirst_name(), User.getLast_name());
Contacting.setUser(User);

//for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    String bytes=contactDAO.getImages(137+"/before/"+1);

    String Url = "data:image/png;base64," + Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes.getBytes());
    //imageUrls.add(url);
//}

ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("ContactForm");
model.addObject("Contacting", Contacting);
model.addObject("Url", Url);
return model;}
```

I debug it and get this source:
                                                                                                                        src="data:image/png;base64,aVZCT1J3MEtHZ29BQUFBTlNVaEVVZ..."

i cant see that image in the page anyway and also dont get an error
someone can help me?

Comment: Is "..." at the end of the `data:image` content really there, or did you just edit it for posting here? If it's the former, then you should debug to figure out which step snips the tail of the b64-encoded image body.

Comment: i cut it for posting here but also in real source there is " at the end

Comment: Maybe this is a conversion/encoding problem, I see you're getting the image data as a `String` and encode this `String`'s bytes to base 64. Are you sure that the `bytes` `String` is not already encoded to base 64 ?

Comment: You can try: `String Url = "data:image/png;base64," + bytes`

Comment: Now i get this source:                                        <img style="-webkit-user-select: none; cursor: zoom-in;" alt="fgfg" src="data:image/png;base64,[B@229ff499" width="200" height="200">   but it also dont work

Comment: That looks like you've used `+ bytes.getBytes()` instead of `+ bytes`.